# Partial Data Sandboxes - price?

Tags: sandbox

The new [Partial Data Sandboxes](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_create.htm&language=en) sound extremely useful but to determine how useful they are I need to find out the price - anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer my own question - from the grapevine I'm hearing roughly 20% of annual license cost for a partial data sandbox, and roughly 30% for a full one.

Answer (score 3):

As salesforce has a license based model, much depends on your total amount of licenses and feature setup. As sandboxes are a copy their price is in relation to your production contract.

You'll need to contact your official salesforce account executive for any pricing information.

Answer (score 1):

This Sandbox type is available in Enterprise, Performance, and  Unlimited editions.It depends on licenses you are using. It is priced with your existing production. Contact Salesforce for any price information.

Answer (score 1):

We are a pretty big SFDC UE customer.  Our use case was to copy over some selected custom object values that act as reference/configuration tables rather than going through data loader on each refresh.

This wasn't enough to justify accepting the SFDC quote of one partial data sandbox that was in Maserati-territory, price-wise.

Answer (score 0):

[Flosum](http://www.flosum.com) has created a [definitive guide on Salesforce sandboxes](http://www.slideshare.net/Flosum/the-definitive-guide-to-salesforce-sandbox-flosum). It includes everything you wanted to know about Salesforce Sandboxes.

Comment: the link doesn't have a definite answer to the pricing of partial sandbox. thou it gives a consolidated view of sandboxes, it doesn't directly answer the question.

Comment: I voted up as slice 20 (not sure if this was updated since vote down) has a similar description as answered by codeulike